# Browser com Resposta Ah não para app Ionic

Tags: ng-repeat

Estou desenvolvendo um app com ionic e estou tentando converter um `xml` de `322mb` para `json`, para levar os dados para a página usando `angular js`.

Segue o trecho do código:

```
.controller('ParlamentarCtrl', function($scope, $http){

    $http.get('js/AnoAtual.xml').then(function(response){

        var deputados = [];
        var x2js = new X2JS();
        var anoAtual = x2js.xml_str2json(response.data);
        $scope.deputadoObj = anoAtual.despesas.despesa;

        var numOfDeputados = $scope.deputadoObj.length;
        for(var i = 0; i<numOfDeputados; i++){
            deputados.push({
                name: $scope.deputadoObj[i].txNomeParlamentar
            });
        }
            $scope.nomeDeputados = deputados; 
    });
```

});

mas infelizmente quando chamo o scope `nomeDeputados`, o browser dá um delay e mostra a página Ah,não

Comment: Eu acho que não entendi esse "Ah, não". Poderia explicar? Isso seria uma página de erro?

Comment: Está parecendo mensagem de erro de timeout padrão do Chrome. Seja mais específico em relação a mensagem do browser.

Comment: sim é um erro de mensagem do chrome, mas infelizmente ele não especifica o tipo de erro, mas olhando o fluxo de dados é erro de timeout porque o arquivo é muito grande. estou tentando usar o basex mas estou com problemas na rotina para nodejs não sei como usar o xquery bind